# ES6 import and export modules

Tags: react-native, es6-modules

In the another file I have been imported like this but when I used in a test    I have the error React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. What can be?

```
import  { RateComponent,  mapStateToProps }   from '../components/Rate';
 it ('renders correctly if has data', () => {
    const tree = shallow( <RateComponent dispatch={jest.fn()}/>);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

This is the way how I exported.

```
export 
{
  RateComponent,
  mapStateToProps
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RateComponent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing the default export and see if that works

```
import RateComponent from '../components/Rate';
```

Also you don't need to export `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I used in test mapStateToProps if I don't need to exported?

Comment: You're already importing a connected component which has state to props mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Just Import RateComponent from the file as already pointed out by Clarity. And pass
some props to the RateComponent for the test to shallow render the component and Match
Snapshot

```
it ('renders correctly if has data', () => {
  const props = {
    // ...Define your props here with some values
  };
  const tree = shallow( <RateComponent {...props}/>);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```